# Must closure be element of topology?

Tags: general-topology

I feel very stupid at the moment. Let $$\tau= \{\mathbb{R}, \varnothing , [0,1] \}$$

Of course it is topology.

I am trying to find boundary of $[0,1]$. I use definition stating thtat $Bd(A)=Cl(A)\cap Cl(X\setminus  A)$  for a topological space $(\tau, X)$.

So let me find $Cl([0,1])$. It is obvious that it equals to $\mathbb{R}$. What is less obvious for me is what does $Cl(\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1])$ equal to.

For me it will be $\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]$. Why? Because I use definition of $Cl(A)$ stating that $x\in Cl(A) \Leftrightarrow  \forall _{U_x} \ \ U_x \cap A \neq \varnothing $ where $U_x$ is neigbourhood of $x$.

Of course for every $x \notin [0,1]$ the definition is fulfilled and every $x\in [0,1]$ has neigbourhood of $[0,1]$ such that $[0,1]\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,1]) = \varnothing$ so it cannot be in closure.

From everything above I can say that $Bd([0,1])=\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]$.

What concerns me is that $\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]$ isn't an element of $\tau$. My question is: is it possible that closure, boundary (or even interior) of an open set in topology isn't an element of topology?

Or maybe I have a bias in my thinking (which I presume is the case here)?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is open in $\tau$, so $\mathbb R\setminus [0,1]$ is closed in the topology.

Comment: So I can use the fact that $A$ is closed $\Leftrightarrow \ A=Cl(A)$ which implies that I am right?

Comment: To start with, you claim that $Cl([0,1])=[0,1]$.  This can't be true, because $[0,1]$ isn't even a closed set in this topology.  Or have you adopted the (non-standard) convention that elements of $\tau$ are the *closed* sets?

Comment: @Donkey_2009: I am sorry, I made a mistake here. $Cl([0,1])=\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Of course it's possible. There is no requirement for boundary of a set to be open (i.e, as an element of the topology). Consider $(0,1)$ under the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, the boundary points are $\{0,1\}$ which is not open.

Answer (score 2):

You should recall that the elements of a topology are its open sets, so if the boundary of a set is not in the topology, then it is not open.

- The *closure* of a set $A$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$.
- The *interior* of $A$ is the largest subset of $A$ that is open in the topology.
- The *boundary* of $A$ is the collection of points that are "close" to both the interior and exterior of $A$.

The closure of a closed set is just the set itself and the interior of an open set is also the set itself. The only one of these that is guaranteed to give you an open set in a general topological space is the interior. There's no reason that the boundary or closure have to give an open set, although they can, after all, a set can be both open and closed.

---

To see when the boundary can be open, look at $\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \operatorname{cl}(A) \cap \operatorname{cl}(X \setminus A) $.
If the closure and $A$ and the closure of its complement are open, then the boundary will be open. In any topological space, this will always occur if $A$ is the whole space or the empty set, in which case $\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \emptyset$.

A slightly less trivial example would be a disconnected space for example, think of the subspace $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ of $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology. If $A = (0,1)$, then its boundary will be open (because it's the empty set).